# How to read each file's last modified/arrival time while reading input data from aws s3 using spark batch application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i want to read each file's last modified/arrival time while reading input data from aws s3 using spark batch application.

[image showing last modified time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2NDn.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is two option in my mind:

First option is to get the name of the last modified file using AWS SDK (https://medium.com/faun/identifying-the-modified-or-newly-added-files-in-s3-11b577774729) before starting your job.

The second option is to use Structured Streaming. Unfortunatly structured streaming can only process new files and not modified files. A simple workaround is to instead of modify your file just add a new one (but it is maybe not possible because of your use case..)